# Mongoose nested alias

Tags: mongoose, graphql, mongoose-schema

I have the following field in the MongoDB and I can NOT change the schema of DB

```
phoneNumbers: [
    { phoneNumber: '15141234567', type: 'WORK' },
    { phoneNumber: '15142233667', type: 'CELL' },
    { phoneNumber: '1517654321', type: 'HOME' }
  ],
```

Schema is

```
const schemaPhoneNumber = new Schema({
  type: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["WORK", "CELL", "HOME"],
    alias: "phoneType",  /////////////////////////////////// I have alias the field name
  },
  phoneNumber: String,
});

const GraphQLPhoneType = new GraphQLEnumType({
  name: "PhoneType",
  values: {
    WORK: {
      value: "WORK",
    },
    CELL: {
      value: "CELL",
    },
    HOME: {
      value: "HOME",
    },
  },
});
const GraphQLPhoneNumber = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "PhoneNumber",
  fields: () => ({
    phoneType: { ////////////////////////////////////// it is not finding by this name
      type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLPhoneType),
    },
    phoneNumber: {
      type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
    },
  }),
});
```

Problem: when I run a query, it is showing the "**phoneNumber**" but the "**phoneType**" return null.

If I change "**phoneType**" to "**type**", the query shows the correct type (WORK, CELL, etc.), but I have to use "phoneType" in graphQL and "type" is DB.

what is the issue, when I have changed by an alias, that it is not available in fields of "GraphQLPhoneNumber", is it a problem of nested JSON or shall I call alias in different way?

Answer (score 0):

The alias is correct, the issue was I did not call schemaPhoneNumber when I create the upper-level schema.

```
phoneNumbers: [schemaPhoneNumber],
```